# Wrong accented characters due to missing charset info?

Tags: macos, email, character-encoding

I just received the following e-mails where all "é" are turned into "Ž", eg. "prŽcŽdent" instead of "précédent".

Am I correct in understanding that it's due to the originating e-mail client running on a Macintosh without sending the charset infos so that other clients (Windows, Unix) can turn accented characters into their correct equivalent?

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.2 \(1499\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1499)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Apple Mail usually adds charset info in mail headers ([example](http://blackgoldsynchro.com/mail/.blackgold@blackgoldsynchro_com/new/1389646244.H956732P30968.box609.bluehost.com,S=3134)). Maybe this particular client is misconfigured. Could you show the whole email (headers and body)?

Comment: Thanks but the rest of the header contains no information that's relevant (just routing). I'll google for infos on how to configure Apple Mail to include charset infos.

Comment: In my latest version of Mail (8.2 on Yosemite) there is even no option to change it. The encoding is detected automatically and proper header is set (I tested it). But I remember that in older versions (maybe yours) that was configurable.